# tornado async post error 500 but curl OK

Tags: python, tornado

URL is `http://*.*.*.*/100/?id=1&version=1`

params is

```
{"cityId": "110000", "query": {"queryStr": "line1", "queryExp": ""}, "channelId": "house"}
```

curl command is:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"cityId": "110000", "query": {"queryStr": "line1", "queryExp": ""}, "channelId": "house"}' "http://*.*.*.*/100/?id=1&version=1"
```

but when I use tornado(4.2) `AsyncHTTPClient`, I got error:

```
tornado.application:Future exception was never retrieved: Traceback (most recent call last):
...
HTTPError: HTTP 500: Internal Server Error
```

I request like this:

```
@gen.coroutine
def request(self, url, method="GET", headers=None, data=None):
    logger.debug(method)
    logger.debug(headers)
    logger.debug(data)
    headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
    }
    req = HTTPRequest(
        url,
        method=method,
        headers=headers,
        body=urllib.urlencode(data).encode('utf-8')
    )
    http_response = yield self.r.fetch(
        # req,
        # self.handle_request
        url,
        method=method,
        headers=headers,
        body=urllib.urlencode(data).encode('utf-8')
    )
    # logger.debug(http_response)
    raise gen.Return(json.loads(http_response.body))
```

Comment: And how are you calling this `request` function? You have `method="GET"` in the python code but `-X POST` on the curl command line.

Comment: I call it the function like this(method equals "POST"):
`body = yield r.request(
        url,
        method=doc["method"],
        headers=doc["headers"],
        data=doc["data"]
    )`

Answer (score 0):

You're sending `'content-type': 'application/json',` but encoding the data with `body=urllib.urlencode(data).encode('utf-8')`. Use `json.dumps` instead of `urllib.urlencode`.

Comment: thx, I tried your advise, and no 500 status error, but I got this:
`raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")`
when return in the request function

Comment: that's a different issue and should probably be a separate question. print out `http_response.code`, `http_response.headers`, and `http_response.body` to see what you're getting from the server. is it really giving you json? (you didn't post the output of your curl command)

Comment: @BenDarnell I have met the same issue with the asker. While I raise HTTPError in the HTTPVerb methods and meanwhile I re-implement the default `write_error` method. But it doesn't work. Could the `write_error` method be called when we use the `gen.coroutine` ?

Comment: @RyanChou I don't see what your situation has to do with this question or answer (which don't mention write_error anywhere). Please post it as a question with more details instead of making comments on a months-old answer.

Comment: @BenDarnell I have tried another way to catch exceptions occur in coroutines and invoked  `self._handle_request_exception(e)` to fixed this issue. I originally overrided the `RequestHandler.write_erorr` method to implement my custom write error json response template. While I used `gen.coroutine` to async my HTTPVerb methods (`get/post/patch`). and meantime. I raise `HTTPError` inside those methods. But it haven't call the `send_error` to invoke `write_error` methods. It drives me so confused.

Comment: @BenDarnell I have to get insight into tornado `RequestHandler` and `gen.coroutine` source codes to figure it out why it couldn't call the `write_error` by default. And found that the `gen.coroutine` haven't invoke the `send_error` -> `write_error` called chain. I have to catch the exceptions which occur in coroutines. and invoke `self._handle_request_exception(err)` to call my override `write_error` method.